# Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 28: connect() timed out! thrown in /src/src322/base_facebook.php on line 1012

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

Since Yesterday, I began to get Curl Timeouts errors, on my FB Apps.
I'm using php-sdk 3.2.3 (At moment I cannot upgrade to 4.0 because I'm still using php5.3), I was updating one FB script to API 2.0, when without any apparent reasons, all the FB Apps on my server started to give the same timeout error.

I tryed to debug the code isolating just a few row of code, the result is a respond time of about 10 sec for every FB call
any tips?
thanks

Comment: i had a similar problem. I updated to the latest version of the SDK and the problem went away.